# Why extension disappear after restarting the browser (in developer mode)?

Tags: opera-extension

There are three extensions loaded in developer mode in Opera 45.0.2531.0 (PGO). After restarting the browser, two of them dissapeared. I do not see any significant difference between the manifest files. Have any ideas?

Comment: Is there any message? Are the extensions installed from https://addons.opera.com? The extension might be blacklisted or its files modified after installation which disables the extension.

Comment: Without any messages, this my extensions, loaded as developer mode from folder with sources.